# adding comma to input values while scanning from QRCode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qr-code

I am doing QRcode scanning and inserting the values of that QR code into the input field. The problem being, it is inserting values without any comma or space.

```
  <input id="code_id_value" type="text" ng-model="getID" name="" value="" class="form-control" autofocus>
```

Js code for getting the value

```
$('#code_id_value').on({
   keypress: function () { typed_into = true; },
     change: function () {
          if (typed_into) {
              
              typed_into = false; //reset type listener
          } else {
              alert('not type');
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Does the data of the QR code actually contain commas/spaces?

Comment: Can you try to add `$(this).value+=$(this).value + ", " ` in your if statement

Comment: @ozgar You're mixing jQuery and vanilla. You also seem to be mixing `=` and `+=`. I believe it'd be `this.value += ', ';` though I don't think that will solve anything.

Comment: No, it's a numeric number @Ouroborus

Comment: @ozgur not working

Comment: @Ouroborus yes, I was mistaken sorry. I was trying to add comma at end of the values when onchange event fired

Comment: You're using a scanning device that connects to the computer as though it were a keyboard? Does the device emit `enter` at the end of a scan? (Single line text boxes treat these as a form submit. If you don't have a form element, `enter` is ignored.)

Comment: Yes, I am using a scanning device. Yes it emits enter at the end of a scan @Ouroborus

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question and comments: You have a QR code scanning device which simulates a keyboard. Each scan automatically includes a terminating <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You want separators inserted between each scan in your `<input>` element. You don't have a `form` element, so <kbd>Enter</kbd> is being ignored.

You would capture the `keypress` event and use that to detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If that key is detected, insert a comma at the end of the `<input>` value.

```js
$('#code_id_value').on({
  keypress: function(event) {
    const key = event.originalEvent.key;
    if(key == 'Enter') {
      event.target.value += ',';
    }
  },
});
```

Another solution would be to use a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead. `<textarea>` is multi-line capable and you would get one scan result per line.

Comment: Perfect! I will try with the text area

Comment: @nawazuddin Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it happens to be the best at solving your question.